# Awaiting a configuration load on a service before continuing in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx

In my Angular project, I have a component which needs to retrieve data from an external API. The URL for this API is loaded from a config file at runtime.

my.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.myattr) {
        this.store.dispatch(
          MyActions.getAttrRequest({ attr: params.myattr })
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

An ngrx effect catches that dispatched event and points it to my service which tries to perform a get:

my.apiservice.ts

```
apiUrl: string;
constructor(
    protected config: ConfigLoaderService,
    protected httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {
    config.loadConfigurations().subscribe((conf: Configuration) => {
      this.apiUrl = conf.apiURL;
    });
  }

  get(url, options = {}) {
    const wholeurl = `${this.apiUrl}/api/${url}`;
    if (this.apiUrl === undefined) {
      throw new HttpErrorResponse({
        status: 425,
        statusText: "Too early",
        url: wholeurl,
      });
    }
    return this.httpClient.get(wholeurl);
  }
```

The problem is that for this particular call, the config hasn't been loaded at the point that the get function is called. So I feel like I want to put a pause in this get (and similarly the post, put etc siblings) to defer the method until the config has been read.
Or is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you subscribe to an *observable* of that configuration? Alternatively, if the config is loaded once when the app starts, could you use `APP_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe APP_INITIALIZER looks just the thing. If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Yep, I have it all working now thanks, @jonrsharpe. If you put it as an answer rather than a comment I can mark it as solved and give you the kudos.